# Is there a way to create child rows in a DataTable using static HTML?

Tags: datatables

I'm creating my DataTable using static HTML output by a Django template.

I'd like to use the child rows feature, with:

1. All child rows visible by default
2. Child row HTML generated by a Django template

I can create child rows in the HTML `<table>`, but they of course get treated as main rows. How do I specify that a `<tr>` is a child row associated with the previous row?

e.g.

```html
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <tr><td>George Thomas</td><td>Age 45</td><td>200 lbs</td></tr>
    <tr this-is-a-child-row=true>
        <div>Child row for George Thomas!</div>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Lucinda Thomas</td><td>Age 49</td><td>140 lbs</td></tr>
    <tr this-is-a-child-row=true>
        <div>Child row for Lucinda Thomas!</div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you checked [the doc](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)?

Comment: yes, that doesn't show how to create static child rows at DOM load time, that shows how to dynamically insert child rows using javascript